# I get the "Cannot read property 'push' " AngularJS, navigator.gelocation

Tags: angularjs, geolocation, navigator

When i try push to an array and I have error "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined".

```
$scope.projectList = [];              

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function($scope,position) {
  $scope.projectList.push(position.coords.latitude);

}, function(error) {
  alert('Unable to get location: ' + error.message);
}, {maximumAge: 0, timeout: 6000, enableHighAccuracy: true })
```

Comment: is this all of your code?? This looks fine but the problem might be some where else!!

Comment: I cut only the beginning:
hivin.controller('locController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

Comment: try removing `$scope` parameter from `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function($scope,position) {` and make it `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {`

Comment: Error missing, but still not pushing

Comment: console.log on `position.coords.latitude` and share what's it giving

Comment: colsole.log(position.coords.latitude) contains is correct, also the AngularJS plugin show in Scope "projectList" Array with coordinat, but not push